# Adding a new line in MatDialog Content Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using MatDialog and trying to add a new line in the content definition. Both `\n` and `</b>` are not doing it. Is there another way without having to manually go into the html and change it since it's a reusable component:

```
var status: MatDialogRef<GenericDialogComponent> this.dialog.open(GenericDialogComponent,{
     width: '400px',
    data: {title: "Sample Title?", content: "Document " + this.docID + " has been saved. The users email address is provied below:\n\n"+this.email+"</b>"} });
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{data.title}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>{{data.content}}</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="Cancel()">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="Ok()" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple <br> doesn't work either? I'm assuming it doesn't take HTML

Comment: No it doesn't  work and it doen's take html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [innerHTML] property:

```
<p [innerHTML]="data.content"></p>
```

and instead of *\n\n*, use the html br tag.

```
const status: MatDialogRef<GenericDialogComponent> this.dialog.open(GenericDialogComponent,{
     width: '400px',
    data: {title: "Sample Title?", content: `Document ${this.docID} has been saved. The users email address is provied below:<br /><b>${this.email+}</b>`} });
```

Comment: does the `</br>` go in the quotes like `'next line </b>'` because it is still not doing it but still debugging thanks

Comment: Why are you using </b> without an opening <b>?

Comment: @Flash I have updated my answer eith the corrent content string (using template string).

Comment: that's so weird it was because I didn't have the opening? with @TimVns answer it worked without it?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<div mat-dialog-content [innerHtml]="'<p>' + data.content + '</p>'">
```

EDIT
@Christian Benseler's answer is better/prettier.

Comment: It's not innerHtml, it is innerHTML

Comment: It does not matter, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the [`<pre>` HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) if you need/want to use `\n`.

But I would suggest [Christian Benseler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55653119/10330923) !

Answer (score 1):

In case others find it useful when hitting this answer, for my needs, I have copied the configuration of a generic dialog and service from [Building a reusable dialog module with Angular Material](https://itnext.io/building-a-reusable-dialog-module-with-angular-material-4ce406117918)

And by using the earlier answer where HTML `<br/>` was set into the string in code, I separated out this by using a Pipe (useful in other display needs too), of course this assumes a dialog is only doing a small amount of data display not showing a whole book chapter ;-)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'newlineToBR',
})
export class NewlineToBRPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  }
}
```

in the common dialog component:

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
      <p class="dialog-message" [innerHTML]="data.message | newlineToBR"></p>
    </div>
```

then in the component calling the dialog, there is no HTML tags, just make sure to add in newlines in editor and use the correct quote mark type:

```
const options = {
title: 'Confirm De-select of Review Required',
message: `If you select OK then all the following fields will be reset:
- start date
- assigned person`,
cancelText: 'CANCEL',
confirmText: 'OK',
```

};

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
        let warningMessages = ['message1','message2','message3'];

        const config=  {
            panelClass:'msg-dialog-container',
            data: {
                type:WARNNING,
                showConfirm:true,
                message: warningMessages
            }};
```