# confirmDialogRef line break

Tags: angular

I'm trying to insert a line break in a message from confirmDialogRef 
ç

```js
this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage = "Are you sure you want to delete the ack logs? \n This action can't be undone"
```

but it's not working.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: may be <br/> can help?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652927/adding-a-new-line-in-matdialog-content-angular-7)